Agora Not Working After Building Application in Production Mode
I am developing a 1v1 chat application using Agora. In the development environment (development-client) of React Native, I can successfully establish communication between two users with audio and video. However, when I compile the application in production or preview, Agora returns the error: -7.
I am using tokens for the rooms and an SSL connection with the server that generates the access tokens. Am I missing something? How can I resolve this issue?
I tried several code modifications, including improving token handling and switching the configuration from "Testing" to "Live" in the Agora Console, but none of these changes made the error disappear.
Here's my engine function:
  const initEngine = async () => {
    if (!_engine.current) {
      _engine.current = createAgoraRtcEngine();
      _engine.current.initialize({
        appId: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_AGORA_APP_ID,
      });
      console.log("Engine initialized successfully");
    }
    _engine.current.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfileType.ChannelProfileLiveBroadcasting);
    _engine.current.setClientRole(ClientRoleType.ClientRoleAudience);

    _engine.current.enableVideo();
    _engine.current.startPreview();

    _engine.current.addListener("onLocalAudioStateChanged", (state) => {
      console.log(state);
    });

    _engine.current.addListener("onUserJoined", (connection, uid) => {
      setHostUid(uid);
    });

    _engine.current.addListener("onUserOffline", async (connection, uid) => {
      await endCall();
   });

    _engine.current.addListener("onError", async (err) => {
      await endCall();
    });

    _engine.current.addListener("onJoinChannelSuccess", (connection, uid) => {
      setJoined(true);
    });

    _engine.current.addListener("onConnectionStateChanged", (state, reason) => {
      console.log("Connection state changed:", state, reason);
    });
  };

